# Converting from Option<&str> to Option<String>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to simplify this syntax in rust:

```rust
struct Foo{
    _a: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let _unused = Foo {_a: Some("foobar".to_string())};
}
```

to not use the `to_string()` method anymore.
Is there a way to automatically enforce the creation of the structure to create a copy of the slice into a new String object? Something like:

```rust
let _unused = Foo {_a: Some("foobar")};
```

The structure cannot hold a reference and needs a String object (API compatibility).

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=593288e971428992a8e5c0a5712f7478)

Comment: Why are you so desperate to remove the `to_string()`? If it's because of repetitions, then you might want to utilize a macro. Otherwise, I don't see what's wrong with it. You could alternatively write `String::from("foobar")` or `Some("foobar".into())`

Comment: I may be biased, but I see it as boilerplate and perhaps something I'm doing wrong.
How would the macro impl look like?

Comment: I'd disagree that it is boilerplate, `&str` and `String` are different types, and you need a method to convert between them. You will have to have that conversion somewhere, whether it's in your calling code or in a method.

Comment: With macro I meant, if you have to write the entire `Foo {_a: Some("foobar".to_string())}` 100 times somewhere, it might be worth creating a macro that produces the entire code section to reduce code duplication. Of course it depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is making a generic constructor that accepts any argument that's `Into<String>`:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo{
    _a: Option<String>,
}

impl Foo {
    fn new<S: Into<String>>(a: S) -> Self {
        Self { _a: Some(a.into()) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::new("abc");
    println!("{:?}", foo);
    // Foo { _a: Some("abc") }
}
```

Comment: Hi BallpointBen, that's a nice idiom! I'm afraid it's very verbose when the structure has a lot of fields (difficult to know which input corresponds to which field).

Comment: I managed to do it through a second structure but I don't like the design, is there a better way?

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bc81ce306f663287865c3f11e79aa571

Comment: If you were ok with explicit `into`s, you could have done `Foo { _a: Some("string".into()) }` from the start.

Comment: But that's the same as repeating to_string() everywhere. For a lot of fields it becomes bothersome.

Comment: You can replace the `match` with a call to `Option::map`, which is a lot less verbose: `input._a.map(str::to_string)`.